# `strtotime` bug when using + 1 month from January

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I' m trying to make a ajax calendar with multiple tabs for a date range previously entered.
But for example:

I want get the next month, it prints march instead of february

```
$start= "2013-01-31";
$current =  date('n', strtotime("+1 month",$start)) //prints 3
```

I think thats occurs because february 2014 is 28 and add +31 like base from the start month but why?

Comment: What is the "whole date" (rather than just the month) when you do that? Does it seem to add 31?

Comment: January 31st + 1 month = February 31st = March 3rd (or March 2nd if leap year)

Comment: FYI `strtotime` takes an unix timestamp as the second param - NOT a string.

Comment: How can i take always the next month from a date range ? THKS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to add one month to the date `2013-01-31`. It should give 31th Feburary 2013, but since the date doesn't exist, it moves on to the next valid month (which is March).

You can use the following work-around:

```
$current = date('n', strtotime("first day of next month",strtotime($start)));
```

Using `DateTime` class:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-01-31');
$date->modify('first day of next month');
echo $date->format('n');
```

This will correctly output `2`.

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/59542)